# Producer/Consumer implementation: Stuck in consumer loop

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, locking, pthreads

I am trying to implement a producer/consumer problem using `pthread` in C. I have a global variable `int num_available` as the state variable of my two conditional variables `fill` and `empty`.

Here is my producer code, which should fill jobs and signal consumers.

```
void *producer(void *arg){
    // Parse the arguments
    struct producer_arg_struct *real_arg = (struct producer_arg_struct*) arg;
    char *data = real_arg -> data;
    size_t filesize = real_arg -> filesize;

    // Start the producer loop
    while(cur_chunk < data + filesize){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("producer got lock, items: %d\n", num_available);

        // Wait for consumers
        while(num_available == MAX){
            printf("producer: sleep\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &mutex);
        }

        // At least one work to fill
        cur_chunk += CHUNK_SIZE;
        cur_result++;
        num_available++;

        pthread_cond_signal(&fill);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is my consumer code, which should complete jobs and signal consumer.

```
void *consumer(void *arg){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("consumer: got lock, item: %d\n", num_available);
        while(num_available == 0){
            // No works available
            printf("consumer: sleep\n");
            pthread_cond_wait(&fill, &mutex);
        }

        // Having at least one work available, do the work
        num_available--;
        compress(cur_chunk, cur_result);

        // Signal producer
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

My programs would fall in a infinite loop. There are two output cases:

1. Producer gets the lock first:

   ```
   producer got lock, items: 0
   consumer: got lock, item: 1
   consumer: got lock, item: 0
   consumer: sleep
   consumer: sleep
   consumer: sleep
   ...
   ```
2. Consumer gets the lock first:

   ```
   consumer: got lock, item: 0
   consumer: sleep
   consumer: sleep
   consumer: sleep
   ...
   ```

It seems like the `pthread_cond_wait(&fill, &mutex)` call in `consumer()` does't really release the lock or put that consumer to sleep. Instead, it is stuck in that infinite loop.

How should I fix it? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to at least signal consumer **before** start waiting for it.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Could be as simple as `num_available` not being `volatile`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish this can help you. 
producer and consumer thread problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define MAX 10000000000                 
//#define MAX 10
pthread_mutex_t the_mutex;
pthread_cond_t condc, condp;
int maxbuf=5 ;   // max produce count.
int buffer = 0;

void* producer(void *ptr) {
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);     /* protect buffer */
        printf("produce:get lock\n") ;

        if(buffer==maxbuf) {
          printf("produce:wait! maxbuffer.\n") ;
      pthread_cond_wait(&condp, &the_mutex);
          printf("produce:wake--\n") ;
        }
    buffer++;
        printf("produce: buffer=%d\n", buffer) ;
    pthread_cond_signal(&condc);        /* wake up consumer */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);  
        usleep(rand()%100);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}
void* consumer(void *ptr) {
  int i;
  for (i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&the_mutex);    
        printf("consume:get lock\n") ;
    if (buffer == 0)     /* If there is nothing in the buffer then wait */
        {
                printf("consume: wait! empty.\n") ;
      pthread_cond_wait(&condc, &the_mutex);
          printf("consume: wake--.\n") ;
        }
    buffer--;
        printf("consume: buffer=%d\n", buffer) ;
    pthread_cond_signal(&condp);        /* wake up producer */
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&the_mutex);  
        usleep(rand()%100);
  }
  pthread_exit(0);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  pthread_t pro, con;
  // Initialize the mutex and condition variables
  /* What's the NULL for ??? */
  pthread_mutex_init(&the_mutex, NULL);
  pthread_cond_init(&condc, NULL);              /* Initialize consumer condition variable */
  pthread_cond_init(&condp, NULL);              /* Initialize producer condition variable */
  // Create the threads
  pthread_create(&con, NULL, consumer, NULL);
  pthread_create(&pro, NULL, producer, NULL);
  // Wait for the threads to finish
  // Otherwise main might run to the end
  // and kill the entire process when it exits.
  pthread_join(con, NULL);
  pthread_join(pro, NULL);
  // Cleanup -- would happen automatically at end of program
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&the_mutex);    /* Free up the_mutex */
  pthread_cond_destroy(&condc);         /* Free up consumer condition variable */
  pthread_cond_destroy(&condp);         /* Free up producer condition variable */
}
```

the output is this...
two threads race.

```
consume:get lock
consume: buffer=2
produce:get lock
produce: buffer=3
produce:get lock
produce: buffer=4
consume:get lock
consume: buffer=3
consume:get lock
consume: buffer=2
produce:get lock
```

if empty

```
produce:get lock
produce: buffer=1
consume:get lock
consume: buffer=0
consume:get lock
consume: wait! empty.
produce:get lock
produce: buffer=1
consume: wake--.
consume: buffer=0
produce:get lock
produce: buffer=1
consume:get lock
```

if max produce.

```
produce:get lock
produce: buffer=5
consume:get lock
consume: buffer=4
produce:get lock
produce: buffer=5
produce:get lock
produce:wait! maxbuffer.
consume:get lock
consume: buffer=4
produce:wake--
produce: buffer=5
produce:get lock
```